# Force ipad to ask Apple ID password when install new software

Tags: ipad, apple-id, password, ipados, parental-controls

I understand it’s convenient  [to avoid entering a password when using app store](https://superuser.com/questions/717573/how-to-save-my-apple-id-password-for-app-store-without-typing-password-every-tim).

For parental control purpose, how can I **enforce** the use of apple id password when using the app store **every time**?

Comment: Setting up Family Sharing might be the easiest approach here.

Comment: @nohillside this is the only apple device in the family, there is no need for family sharing

Comment: There is a need for family sharing to accomplish your goal. I’ll put up an answer and provide other options since it’s about two accounts and not two devices in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a second Apple ID as part of family sharing and use that ID for the App Store only. You can choose to use the primary ID on the rest of the device or let that ID be off device once you are set up.

If you want a more complicated setup, you will need an MDM provider which can also do this, with extra work past what Apple has designed to exert parental control over Apple ID functions.

- [Apple Support: Choose an MDM solution](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/choose-an-mdm-solution-dep1d7afa557/web)
- [JumpCloud](https://jumpcloud.com/pricing) - free for 10 devices
- [Mosyle](https://business.mosyle.com/)  - free tier for business and [for education](https://school.mosyle.com/)

Comment: Thank you for very much.  I want a simple solution to control app install only, if apple provide solution for controlling app running (i.e. require a password to launch app) that would be very nice.  But I prefer to avoid any external/expert tools, because I have literally no experience using apple devices.

Comment: I’m sure you’re in the same situation many others have been @xrfang - are you sure you can’t just block the App Store on the device with parental controls and a pin? It seems you can manage payment card, in app settings and access to the app if you have to block free software from being installed.

Comment: I am sorry that I have abosolutely no knowledge about apple device and ecosystem.   The ipad was given to my child as a gift by a relative. Now I would like to control any (no matter it's free or not) application installation activity (i.e. ONLY I can install software), but there is no need to control usage of the device.  So please advice if you have any simpler way to achieve this. Thanks a lot.